# load a jsp page in dialog element (html5) using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to load a jsp page in dialog element. Here is the code. Instead of the code written inside the dialog element, I want a complete jsp page to load in it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function dialogShow() {
    document.getElementById("dialog").showModal();
};
function dialogClose() {
    document.getElementById("dialog").close();
};
</script>
<style>
dialog {
  border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
dialog::backdrop {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<dialog id="dialog">
  <p>This is a html5 modal dialog</p>
  <button id="close" onclick="dialogClose()">Close</button>
</dialog>
<button id="show" onclick="dialogShow()">Open Dialog!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use an iframe  <dialog><iframe src="xxx.jsp"></iframe></dialog>

Comment: @Sunand Sorry to bother you again, but now i am unable to close the dialog from the jsp that opened inside the iframe

Comment: you can write javascript in the jsp page saying window.parent.dialogClose()

Comment: It gives me an error - Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match

Comment: please check that the iframe and the page u opened are using same domain. even if one has www.x.com and only x.com it wont work.

Comment: But i am using local html files on this. So i don't think there is any possibility of domain mismatch